# AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'time'

Tags: python, python-3.x, runtime-error, attributeerror, python-datetime

I am using Python 3.7 and trying to learn `datetime` module from library, but I am getting `AttributeError`. code below:

```
import datetime

t = datetime.time(4, 20, 1)

# Let's show the different components
print(t)
print('hour  :', t.hour)
print('minute:', t.minute)
print('second:', t.second)
print('microsecond:', t.microsecond)
print('tzinfo:', t.tzinfo)
```

As run file I get this error `AttributeError: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'time'`

Please Help me to find where I am going wrong. Thanks

Comment: Do you have a file in your working directory called "datetime.py"?

Comment: Either your installation is broken or, as mentioned by Daniel, you have a file called `datetime` somewhere which is hiding the built-in modulo. What does `print(datetime.__file__)` output?

Comment: According to Python 3.7 documentation, your code should work. https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html I guess your problem has a different reason.

Comment: Your code seems to work: https://onlinegdb.com/SyHDJYDtX most likely a problem with your python or project files as the others have mentioned

Comment: Your code works, so like said before, you probably check your project's others files. Try to isolate your code outside your project, and run your py file. If it works, check your project, if it doesn't, check your python conf

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem may be that your python file has the same name as the datetime module, maybe you called your program file ***datetime.py***.

You need to rename your program file and delete any eventual .pyc file generated in your path, then you can import the correct datetime module.